# extracting specific Cookies from the Cookie Jar using Python

Tags: python, regex, session, web-scraping, cookies

I am trying to extract cookies from chrome for a specific site using python **browser_cookie3** module. Site Name:nseindia.com

This (Working) code was handed out to us and is turning to be Rather slow because disk read-write is required. Also there are some dependancies and code isn't very effective.

Code snippet:

```
import browser_cookie3, csv, re
cj = browser_cookie3.chrome()
cookielist = list(browser_cookie3.chrome())
cookies = str(cj)
CookieFile = open('c:\\temp\\temp2.txt','w+')
CookieFile.write(cookies)
CookieFile.close()
with open('c:\\temp\\temp2.txt', newline='') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
cookies_list = next(reader) 
#this traverses thru each item in the list and displays the cookie as well as the value.
for elem in cookies_list:
    mycook = re.search(r'for .nseindia.com/>',elem)
    if mycook:
        thiselem = str(elem)
        print(re.search(r'<Cookie (.+?)for \.nseindia\.com', thiselem).group(1))
```

Now, I have already tried to extract all 6 items (from nseindia.com), using re.search which didn't give me the desired results.

below is what i have already tried:

```
cookies = str(cj)
re.search('<Cookie RT=(.*?)for .nseindia.com',cookies).group(1)
```

Additionally we also tried to change the cookie object into a list and then extract , it failed.
when we tried to convert the String object (varname = cookie) into a list and then try to extract using re.search that also failed.

My ask: If someone can give me a reliable way to achieve the above functionality in an effective and efficient way it will be highly appreciated. TIA

Comment: It does not work on my end, `cj = browser_cookie3.chrome()` throws `browser_cookie3.BrowserCookieError: Failed to find Chrome cookie`

Comment: Thanks for trying Wiktor, possibly your browser_cookie3 isn't working, or perhaps there is a different version of Chrome. I am using Ver 87

Comment: If you need help, you could share the contents of `c:\\temp\\temp2.txt`. Or at least some example of what you are trying to get. I cannot run your code, it is not reproducible.

Comment: the contents of temp2.txt is very large to share, here is a snippet.. 

<Cookie AKA_A2=A for .nseindia.com/>, <Cookie RT="sl=3&ss=kkbfh0dv&tt=38z&z=1&dm=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Way to achieve the result without a Disk read-write,

```
import browser_cookie3,re
cj = browser_cookie3.chrome()
cookies = str(cj)
cookielist = cookies.split(",")
for elem in cookielist:
    mycook = re.search(r'for .nseindia.com/>',elem)
    if mycook:
        thiselem = str(elem)
        print(re.search(r'<Cookie (.+?)for \.nseindia\.com', thiselem).group(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import browser_cookie3,re
cj = browser_cookie3.chrome()
results = re.findall(r'<Cookie\s([^<>]+?)\sfor\s\.nseindia\.com', str(cj))
```

If you want to print and seem them all, either use `print(results)`, or `for r in results: print(r)`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hxjKfH/1). *Details*:

- `<Cookie` - a `<Cookie` string
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `([^<>]+?)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `<~ and` >` as few as possible
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `for` - `for`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `\.nseindia\.com` - `.nseindia.com` string.